# Convert signed to unsigned integer mathematically

Tags: math, integer, signed, unsigned-integer

I am in need of an unsigned 16 bit integer value in my OPC server but can only send it a signed 16 bit integer.  I need to change this signed integer to unsigned mathematically but am unsure how.  My internet research has not lead me in the right path either.  Could someone please give some advise?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What programming language are you using to write this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mathematically, the conversion from signed to unsigned works as follows: (1) do the integer division of the signed integer by `1 + max`, (2) codify the signed integer as the non-negative remainder of the division. Here `max` is the maximum integer you can write with the available number of bits, 16 in your case.

Recall that the *non-negative remainder* is the only integer `r` that satisfies

```
  1. s = q(1+max) + r
  2. 0 <= r < 1+max.
```

Note that when `s >= 0`, the non-negative remainder is `s` itself (you cannot codify integers greater than `max`). Therefore, there is actually something to do only when `s < 0`:

```
if s >= 0 then return s else return 1 + max + s
```

because the value `r = 1 + max + s` satisfies conditions 1 and 2 above for the non-negative reminder.

For this convention to work as expected the signed `s` must satisfy

```
- (1 + max)/2 <= s < (1 + max)/2
```

In your case, given that you have 16 bits, we have `max = 0xFFFF` and `1 + max = 0x10000 = 65536.`

Note also that if you codify a negative integer with this convention, the result will have its highest bit on, i.e., equal to 1. This way, the highest bit becomes a flag that tells whether the number is negative or positive.

Examples:

```
 2 -> 2
 1 -> 1
 0 -> 0
-1 -> 0xFFFF
-2 -> 0xFFFE
-3 -> 0xFFFD
...
-15 -> 0xFFF1
...
-32768 -> 0x8000 = 32768 (!)
-32769 -> error: cannot codify using only 16 bits.
```

Comment: The first sentence is a bit unclear:
1) What does it mean "sending the remainder"? In the math literature one could not find this term.
2) "divided by `1 + max`": is it related to the "non-negative remainder" or to the "signed integer"?
Please clarify / reformulate.

Comment: Also: 3) In the "This logic works as follows ..." formula where is the "non-negative remainder"?

Comment: @pmor Thanks for your comments. Please let me know if this is clearer now.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the modifications.
However, the text has became a bit long.
A few compact examples (just 1 sentence each!):
1) C++ std: «If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2n where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type)».
2) C std: «... if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of the new type».

Comment: 3) Book: C A Software Engineering Approach: «When an integer value x is converted to a smaller unsigned integer type, the result is the nonnegative remainder of x / (U_MAX+1) where U_MAX is the largest number that can be represented in the shorter unsigned type».
4) DEC C Language Reference Manual: «When an integer value is demoted to an unsigned integer of smaller size, the result is the nonnegative remainder of the value divided by the number one greater than the largest representable unsigned value for the new integral type».